# Outlook 365 - how to show multiple lines in the “To” field

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

I there a way to display multiple lines in the "TO" field (blue lines below) in the reading pane in Outlook 365 like it was possible in Office 2013?

**Office 365:**
[image]

**Office 2013:**
[image]

**EDIT:**
Clicking the down arrow located after the "TO" field opens a non-convenient "tooltip" with full list and scroller which is closed after clicking on anything else.

[image]

Comment: I think that will happen automatically if you click the expand button, which, in your example looks like a +47 and a down arrow.

Comment: @LPChip it doesn't - this down arrow opens a non-convenient "tooltip" with full list and scroller and that's exactly what I would Iike to prevent.

Answer (score 1):

What's the version of Office 365? I checked this behavior on my side. If I click "+87", then it will show as follows:(4 lines)

[image]

[image]

I'm using version 1910 Monthly Channel. Try upgrading Office

Comment: I'm using version 1902 (Build 11328.20438). I've just edited the question and added what I see when clicking the "down arrow"

Comment: That's different from my Outlook client. Are you in monthly channel? What if we upgrade to the newest version?

Comment: I'm working in a big corporate and cannot control the office version installed by IT.